# Cyclic sending of messages to different procces using SendMessage()

Tags: c#, winapi, ipc, sendmessage

UPD: added MCVE.

This is an educational task. I have to use `SendMessage()` function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, 
    uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

I have to make two different applications with GUI communicationg by messages. After getting message like "start" `1 app` have to start sendinding message "Ask value" to `2 app` each 5 seconds. And `2 app` send to `1 app` message "Send value" with some data.

`1 app` is WinForms program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Oven_Monitor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GetCurrentProcessId();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private uint askMessageID      = RegisterWindowMessage("Ask value");
        private uint dataMessageID     = RegisterWindowMessage("Send value");
        private uint registerMessageID = RegisterWindowMessage("Register sensor");

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "Really rare title";
        }

        public void checkSensors() {
            while (true) {
                SendMessage(secondAppHWnd, askMessageID, (UIntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        private IntPtr secondAppHWnd;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            if (m.Msg == registerMessageID) {
                secondAppHWnd = m.LParam;
                Thread tr = new Thread(checkSensors);
                tr.Start();
            } else if (m.Msg == dataMessageID) {
                //do some stuff
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

`2 app` is console project, but it requires `System.Windows.Forms` referens:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HeatSensor
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr mainAppHandle = FindWindow(null, "Really rare title");
            while (mainAppHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
                mainAppHandle = FindWindow(null, "Really rare title");
            }
            HiddenForm form = new HiddenForm(mainAppHandle);

            while (true) //it's actually not infinit
            {
                //do some stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And hidden form class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HeatSensor
{
    public partial class HiddenForm : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        static private IntPtr mainAppHandle;

        public HiddenForm(IntPtr mainAppHWnd)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainAppHandle = mainAppHWnd;
            string title = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
            title += System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            title += System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            this.Text = title;
            this.CreateHandle();
            int currentWindowHandle = (int)FindWindow(null, title);
            SendMessage(mainAppHandle, RegisterWindowMessage("Register sensor"),
                (UIntPtr)0, currentWindowHandle);
        }

        private uint askMessageID = RegisterWindowMessage("Ask value");
        private uint dataMessageID = RegisterWindowMessage("Send value");
        private uint registerMessageID = RegisterWindowMessage("Register sensor");

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == askMessageID)
            {
                SendMessage(mainAppHandle, dataMessageID, (UIntPtr)1, (IntPtr)1);
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason this programs act strange. Almost everytime `2 app` don't getting sended "Ask value" message, sometimes `checkSensors()` send 1-3 messages and stop.

What is wrong?

Both HWnd is correct.

---

Update: I tried to check error here:

```
public void checkSensors() {
    while (true) {
        SendMessage(secondAppHWnd, askMessageID, (UIntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();                
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

And see. As `SendMessage` was performed, this thread was blocked (what means, `SendMessage` was not copleted. After i closed `2 app`, thread was unblocked and i got 164 error (ERROR_MAX_THRDS_REACHED: No more threads can be created in the system.). What it's supposed to mean?

Also, added:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                //here is all message checks
                int erro2r = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (erro2r != 0) {
                    int j; //stop to debug here
                }
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
```

And it just constantly return 1400 ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE (i don't send any messages at that moment).

So it looks totaly unclear to me.

---

update 2: If i call it from `WndProc()`, everything works:

```
SendMessage(secondAppHWnd, askMessageID, (UIntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
```

But i need to send this message from different thread each 5 seconds.

Comment: The `HWND`s may be correct, but your P/Invoke signature is all wrong. You have to use `IntPtr` for `hWnd` and `lParam`. `wParam` should use type `UIntPtr`. Likewise, the return value should be `IntPtr`. If you want to stay CLS-compliant, use `IntPtr` for all of the above.

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you! I fixed this, but main problem is still here.

Comment: Please make an MCVE. Stop calling RegisterWindowMessage more than once. Add error checking. Also please consider doing some debugging. Attempting to program without debugging is not productive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, made MCVE. I really tried to debug this, but i can't find any reason of this behavior.

Comment: You don't check for errors anywhere.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, do you mean exceptions handling? I thought, all exceptions interrupt program. But nothing like this happens. Any exceptions may be ignored by system?

Comment: No. The Win32 functions you call don't raise exceptions. You don't check for errors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, can't find any way to handle this kind of errors. Please give me advise.

Comment: The documentation explains it. Start by reading that.

Comment: Console apps don't have message pumps by default, so there is nobody available to pick up the inbound message.

Comment: @RaymondChen, for this reason i run hidden form to deal with messages and it recieve them successfully. Problem starts as i try to send it from `checkSensors()`.

Comment: It's not clear what thread is running the hidden form. That thread needs to pump messages. The fact that the `SendMessage` to the hidden form hangs strongly suggests that the hidden form is on a thread that is not pumping messages.

Comment: @RaymondChen, finally found solution.

Answer (score -1):

So, it finally works if both programs is WinForms projects. I can just run console window from `2 app` and hide main window.

Comment: This is not so much a solution as workaround. You gave up trying to understand message pumps and just switched to a different design where somebody else runs the message pump for you.